# Notepad++ Removing lines with X number of same words

Tags: notepad++

I do not want to specify the words, I just want to automatically detect lines with similar words.

For example, all these lines would be deleted due to having 2+ similar words.

1. **Lovely** days in the **garden**
2. I live in a **lovely garden**
3. **Lovely garden** love

Answer (score 1):

This is too complex and can't be done with just notepad++ alone. You'll need to script this using something like vbscript, etc.